# Saving as iwb(Interactive whiteboard) file format

Tags: cocoa

how can i save a file as iwb(interactive whiteboard ) file format in cocoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely no built-in functionality to do this. You will need to write the code yourself. File format specifications appear to be [here.](http://industry.becta.org.uk/display.cfm?resID=39694)